# React-Native build release apk Failed to execute aapt

Tags: java, android, react-native, build, release

App works in debug mode just fine by running `react-native run-android`

But, when I try to build in relase mode by running `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

it gives me this error:

`android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..
error: failed parsing overlays.`

`Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt`

I tried workarounds like putting `android.enableAapt2=false` and `org.gradle.configureondemand=true` in android/gradle.properties

They both helped me create signed apk but app was crashing on start,
I tried to debug that crash by `adb logcat` and error is:

`FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-139
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server.`

Please help me out, I cant seem to figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if anyone wonders, we ended up downgrading gradle to

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`

and it worked.